# Display Configurable Product which is OUT OF STOCK at last in product list

Tags: magento, configurable-product

i need a help.I have my website which combines both simple and configurable products.I applied code from community to sort products by their quantity.It works great for simple product,but it seems that it is not working properly for configurable product.I am working on 1.7.I try a lot to find the solution for it,any help will be greatly appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: Configurable products always have zero qty.

Comment: yes..but i want to sort by its associated product's quantity.